# Is there any other advantage of AWS EC2 besides flexibility and scalability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have several web-based projects or apps and their server side programs are currently running on a VPS. I found out the AWS EC2 service recently and I'm quite curious about whether it's better for my situation. I've searched up on Google for some nice and simple explanations of the pros and cons of EC2, but some of the articles are a little complicated and confusing and I didn't really understand. I did, however, understand they're saying two big things of EC2 are flexibility and scalability. But these two don't seem to apply to my situation. All my projects or apps are nonprofit highly customized private services. Normally they're invite only and I don't really expect a lot of people to use them. So I don't really worry about what if they grow so fast and crash my server. As for the cost, EC2 is not necessarily better either. I pay a little below $200 each year for the VPS service and it runs great. I had little trouble with it. EC2 service actually costs a little more than that and I didn't find my apps have better performance running on it. Some people say with EC2 you pay only for what you use but the thing is I can't shutdown my apps just because I think nobody would be using it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

IN your case, sounds like no. If you are paying only $200/year, and everything works to your satisfaction, why mess with it.